# How can I display the site logo in the top header alongside the navigation menu in the Magazine Pro theme using the Genesis framework?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

How can I display the site logo in the top header, where the top navigation menu is located, using the Magazine Pro theme based on the Genesis framework? I have attempted to modify the code by removing and adding actions, as shown below:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
add_action( 'genesis_site_title', 'genesis_do_nav' );
```

Although I can position the logo using `z-index`, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method to achieve the same result. If I can place the header navigation and logo side-by-side, it would eliminate the need for a CSS workaround. Since I am using this customized theme as a foundation, allowing it to be used with other sites by simply changing the logo, I would greatly appreciate any guidance in the right direction.